# How to prevent character quote in python?

Tags: python

How to stop '"' turn into '& quot;' for below code?

```
>>> from xml.dom.minidom import Document
>>> doc=Document()
>>> name_element = doc.createElement('name')
>>> name_text = doc.createTextNode('"tom"')
>>> name_element.appendChild(name_text)
<DOM Text node "'"tom"'">
>>> name_element.toxml()
'<name>&quot;tom&quot;</name>'
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: it seems to be the way it works. Could you explain more why you need to obtain something else?

Comment: The best answer is probably that you should keep &quot; Do you want to write valid xml or not?

Comment: @louic, quotation marks in text node children of elements are not invalid.

Comment: Thanks Aankhen. My mistake.